# Fetch a vertex and all its vertices and edges

Tags: orientdb

I want, from a vertex, to fetch **this vertex itself** and all its outgoing **vertices** and **edges**. I have this :

```
select expand(unionall(@this, outE(), out())) from #1:0
```

This works for edges and vertices but not for the @this element. I get something like this in a field named "value":

```
{"out_Configured":["#2:0","#2:1"]}
```

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1):

I tried running you query and it is working fine in `version 2.0.5`.

If you do not want the output compulsorily in JSON format, you can try the following query:

```
select expand( $f ) LET $a = ( select expand(unionall(outE(), out())) from #1:0 ), $b = ( select from #1:0 ), $f = unionall( $a, $b )
```

Comment: Thanks, I finally did it using fetch plans.